# Get запрос. Получение определенного параметра

Tags: javascript, postman

Что я делаю не так. Я хочу получить все id в user_chests но я написал что то неправильно

```
const result = _.map(pm.response.json().user_chests, data => ({id}))
pm.environment.set("response", JSON.stringify(result))
```

JSON --->

```
{
 "data": {
   "user_chests": [
        {
            "id": 298297391,
            "type": "silver",
            "state": "awaiting",
            "ended_at": -329632
        },
        {
            "id": 298308674,
            "type": "common",
            "state": "awaiting",
            "ended_at": -344031
        },
        {
            "id": 298325353,
            "type": "gold",
            "state": "awaiting",
            "ended_at": -315229
        }
    ]
 }
}
```

**В ответ я ничего не получаю**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Ссылаетесь по неверному ключу на массив `user_chests` и неверно определена [стрелочная функция](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) для извлечения значения `id`.

Попробуйте так:

```
const result = _.map(pm.response.json().data.user_chests, data => data.id)
pm.environment.set("response", JSON.stringify(result))
```

Comment: В ответ я ничего не получаю. Скинул скрин

Comment: @АндрейReyz, а что вы хотите увидеть на экране? Ваш код только устанавливает переменную окружения `response`, которую вы можете использовать в последующих запросах. Если вы хотите посмотреть какое значение присваивается переменной окружения - добавьте в конец кода строчку `console.log(JSON.stringify(result));`,  результат смотрите в консоли.

Comment: так тоже ничего не вывело

Comment: Когда я писал про консоль, то подразумевал консоль postman’a.

Comment: Естественно я все это дело делаю в Postmane, Где Test result там ничего не вывело

Comment: @АндрейReyz, я вам писал про [это](https://pastenow.ru/6STVT). Чтобы в `Test  result` что-то выводилось нужно тесты [создать](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test_scripts/).